# How to insert AutomaticNumbering programmatically?

Tags: cells, notebooks

**Preamble**: I often work with the JournalArticle Stylesheet and use in it the styles "Figure" for graphics and "FigurCaption" for the corresponding caption. The figures should be numbered. To make this I must 1) Select the cell with the graphics and make its style be "Figure", then 2) make a tag for this cell, then 3)  make a new cell below with the style "FigureCaption" and type there "Fig." and finally 5) go to Menu/Insert/AutomaticNumbering and enter a number in a standard way.

It is much too long. Now I am trying to make a function "makeFig" to shorten this procedure. So far, I have the following:

```
makeFig[expr_, tag_String] := Module[{},
  CellPrint[
   Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[expr]], {"Figure", CellTags -> "Fig" <> tag}]];
  CellPrint[Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[Fig ]], {"FigureCaption"}]];
  ]
```

This works, if the StyleSheet is JournalArticle.

Example:

```
makeFig[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], "A"]
```

[image]

**The question**:

*Main*: Have you any idea of how I could programmatically after the word "Fig" insert the automatic numbering?

*Secondary*: In this code, I cannot put the word Fig in quotes like this: "Fig.". If I do that the quotes appear in the resulting image. Therefore, I have to put the word Fig without a point. This is a minor problem, but maybe you know how to easily deal with it too?

**Edit**: The answer to the secondary question may be as follows (thanks to  @Ben Izd):

```
makeFig2[expr_, tag_String] := Module[{},
      CellPrint[
   ExpressionCell[expr, "Figure", TextAlignment -> Center, 
    CellTags -> "Fig" <> tag]];
      CellPrint[
   TextCell["Fig." , "FigureCaption", FontSize -> 12, 
    TextAlignment -> Center]];
      ]
```

The main question still persists.

Comment: I haven't used cell manipulations, so I might be wrong, with regard to your secondary part, when we create a new cell with the `"FigureCaption"` style, it is just a cell without any `Box`, like `CellPrint[Cell["Fig 1", {"FigureCaption"}]]` which solves your problem, is there any reason you chose your code?

Comment: @Ben Izd Thank you. Please have a look at the edit.

Comment: You are most welcome. Since we can create labels with strings, wouldn't a global variable like `$FigureIndex=0` solve the problem? (like `... TextCell["Fig. " <> ToString[$FigureIndex += 1] ...`) or it should be in a specific order other than execution?

Comment: @Ben Izd Yes, it seems to answer my main question. Why do not you give this idea formally as a regular answer to enable me to accept it?

Comment: @Ben Izd I seem to have found a certain drawback in your approach. Since each time it adds a unit to `$FigureIndex` if I want to change something in a figure and evaluate it once more it will increase its number. Moreover, this approach will make it larger than the maximum value of `$FigureIndex=0`in the moment I make the reevaluation of the figure.  I would better like to make the numeration on the vases of the cell tags.

Comment: @Ben Izd And, further, it will not enable me to give references to these figures from the text.

Comment: I was writing a solution that fixed the execution order but I didn't understand "give references", do you mean the execution order or something else? could you elaborate on that?

Comment: I've used something like `CounterBox["Figure"]` or  `CounterBox["Figure", celltag]`. Something like `CellPrint@Cell[TextData[{StyleBox["Fig. ", FontWeight -> "Bold"], StyleBox[CounterBox["Figure"], FontWeight -> "Bold"], StyleBox[".", FontWeight -> "Bold"], "  ", "A caption."}], "FigureCaption"]` for the caption. You can refer to the counter in the cell through its tag: `CellPrint@Cell[TextData[{"In figure ", CounterBox["Figure", "fig:myfirst"], " we see..."}], "Text"]`. See also `CounterIncrements` etc. I used it in stylesheets and editing, not in programming. I think it might work, though.

Comment: (Oops, I forgot to add `CellTags -> "fig:myfirst"` to my first `CellPrint@...` cell.)

Comment: @Michael E2 Thank you once more. Your idea works nicely in the following version: `makeFig2[expr_, 
  tag_String] := (CellPrint[
   Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[expr]], "Figure", CellTags -> "Fig" <> tag]];
  CellPrint@
   Cell[TextData[{StyleBox["Fig. ", FontWeight -> "Bold"], 
      StyleBox[CounterBox["Figure"], FontWeight -> "Bold"], 
      StyleBox[".", FontWeight -> "Bold"], "  "}], "FigureCaption", 
    CellTags -> "fig:myfirst"])`. Could you please kindly explain me why do you need `"fig:myfirst"` here?

Comment: @MichaelE2 (Continuation) This is the tag of the FigureCaptions string equal for all images I will have in the document. I do not understand the role played here by this tag.

Comment: @MichaelE2 One further question: What is the difference of using `CounterBox["Figure"]` and   `CounterBox["Figure", tag]`? They seem to work equally when I test them. Do I miss something?

Comment: Hi, I added an answer that tries to thoroughly address the points you raised, at least as thoroughly as my understanding allows. The functionality is mostly undocumented, so I'm sure there are limits to my understanding.  If you have further questions, ask under my answer. I will try to answer them, if I can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Explanation

[Some of questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270055/how-to-insert-automaticnumbering-programmatically?noredirect=1#comment674022_270055) have come up about how `CounterBox["Figure"]` and  `CounterBox["Figure", tag]` work in the comments under the OP.  This box seem to be an approach that can solve the problem at hand (see also [@Carl Woll's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/270087/4999)), so instead of a potentially long exchange of comments, which have to be short, I thought an answer that can be edited would be more appropriate. I also have a correction to make to my comments.

First, <s>I don't know where there is much documentation on `CounterBox[]`</s> thanks to @BenIzd, there is [this webpage](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/nbarch/2018/10/2018-10-10r84uo/CounterTutorial.nb) that introduces `CounterBox[]` in V3.0.2; it seems to be an HTML version of [this Wolfram Library tech note](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/ID/186/). This answer is based on what I inferred by examining cell expressions of the following:

1. A cell after doing the menu command **Insert > AutomaticNumber...** of tutorial that numbered things.
2. Styles like `"ItemNumbered"` and `"DisplayFormulaNumbered"` in stylesheets like Default.nb (find it with `FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "StyleSheets", "Default.nb"}]`).
3. Tutorials that numbered things.

**`CounterBox[counter]`** — for numbering cells

The one-argument version is typeset by the Front End to show the number of cells with style `counter` from the beginning of a "unit" (my term, see below) up to and including the current cell, ***provided*** the style is counted. (This is the correction I needed to make; see **Counter versus style** below.) It is generally used to label a cell with a number. If you want to have as style that is sometimes numbered and sometimes not, it is better to have two styles like `"DisplayFormula"` and `"DisplayFormulaNumbered"`, with the numbered style inheriting from the unnumbered one.

**`CounterBox[counter, tag]`** — for referring to numbered cells

The two-argument version is typeset by the Front End to show the value of `CounterBox[counter]` in the (first) cell tagged `tag`. The menu command **Insert > Automatic Numbering...** presents a dialog for inserting a `CounterBox[]`. You have to select the style, which it and what documentation there is calls a "Counter".  The style/counter will be automatically initialized with the style of the cell the cursor is in.  And if you also select a tag from the list of tagged cells, it will insert the corresponding two-argument form.  If you type a tag that does not exist in the notebook, the `CounterBox[]` will be displayed as "XXX".

**Options (including "unit")**

One can explore the symbols returned by `Names["Counter*"]`. All but one relate to `CounterBox`. Some are `Cell` options and some are `CounterBox` options.  Some have usage messages, some have documentation pages, and some have neither.  Two are worth mentioning, meaning only that I have something meaningful and seemingly accurate to say about them. See the next section for something about `CounterIncrements`. The other option `CounterAssignments` controls what I called the "unit".  This option causes the cell to reset the counters to the values indicated.  Here is an example of the option value from the default stylesheet for the styles `"Title"` and `"Section"`:

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Title", CounterAssignments}]
(*
{{"Section", 0}, {"Equation", 0}, {"Figure", 0},
 {"Subtitle", 0}, {"Subsubtitle", 0}, {"Item", 0},
 {"Subitem", 0}, {"Subsubitem", 0}, {"ItemNumbered", 0},
 {"SubitemNumbered", 0}, {"SubsubitemNumbered", 0}}
*)

CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Section", CounterAssignments}]
(*
{{"Subsection", 0}, {"Subsubsection", 0}, {"Item", 0},
 {"Subitem", 0}, {"Subsubitem", 0}, {"ItemNumbered", 0},
 {"SubitemNumbered", 0}, {"SubsubitemNumbered", 0}}
*)
```

One can see that, assuming there is just one cell of style `"Title"` at the beginning of the notebook, that `"Equation"` and `"Figure"` are numbered sequentially through the whole notebook.  One can also see that the `"Section"` counter is reset by `"Title"` but not the `"Subsection"` counter. So there is an assumption about the document structure build into the stylesheet.

**"Counter" versus style**

When I initially made my comments, it had been long time since I had really looked at `CounterBox[]`.  I had in mind that the term "Counter" used in Mathematica is interchangeable with "style."  That is not strictly true.  The `CounterBox[counter]` counts the cells whose `CounterIncrements` option value is `counter`.  This is usually set in a stylesheet.  In the default stylesheet, most but not all styles have `CounterIncrements` set to the name of the style. A typical example of not are the styles that have a numbered variant:

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "DisplayFormula",
  CounterIncrements}]
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "DisplayFormulaNumbered", 
  CounterIncrements}]
(*
{}
"DisplayFormulaNumbered"
*)
```

I believe the `Cell` option `CounterIncrements -> {counter,...}` takes a list of counters, where each `counter` is a string. I would guess that multiple cell styles can increment the same counter and that a single cell can increment multiple counters.

#### Example application to OP's task

The following is modified from a [comment by the OP](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270055/how-to-insert-automaticnumbering-programmatically?noredirect=1#comment674018_270055):

```
makeFig3[expr_, tag_String] := (
   CellPrint@Cell[BoxData[
      ToBoxes[expr]], "Figure",
     CounterIncrements -> {"Figure"}, (* N.B. *)
     CellTags -> "Fig" <> tag];       (* N.B. *)
   CellPrint@Cell[TextData[
      {StyleBox["Fig. ", FontWeight -> "Bold"], 
       StyleBox[CounterBox["Figure"], FontWeight -> "Bold"], 
       StyleBox[".", FontWeight -> "Bold"]}],
     "FigureCaption"]);  (* Note no CellTag needed *)
```

Let's make two figures:

```
makeFig3[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], "PlotSin"]
makeFig3[Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], "PlotCos"]
```

Now let's discuss them in a `"Text"` cell, which was created by hand. A question about the use of cell tags was raised in [a comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270055/how-to-insert-automaticnumbering-programmatically?noredirect=1#comment674018_270055).  The cell tags created by `makeFig3[]` are used here for reference.  This text cell needs no tag, at least not for the purpose of referring to the figures.  Likewise the caption cell created by `makeFig3[]` needs no tag.

```
CellPrint@Cell[TextData[
   {"Compare ",
    StyleBox["Fig. ", FontWeight -> "Bold"], 
    StyleBox[CounterBox["Figure", "FigPlotSin"], (* Note tag *)
     FontWeight -> "Bold"], StyleBox[".", FontWeight -> "Bold"], 
    " with ",
    StyleBox["Fig. ", FontWeight -> "Bold"], 
    StyleBox[CounterBox["Figure", "FigPlotCos"], (* Note tag *)
     FontWeight -> "Bold"], StyleBox[".", FontWeight -> "Bold"], 
    "  "}],
  "Text", CellTags -> "foo"]
```

Now let's look at the outputs (I don't have styles `"Figure"` or `"FigureCaption"`, so they display with no cell margins in whatever default styling there is for undefined styles; the `"Text"` cell gets indented, not centered):

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation.

Comment: (+1) Great and comprehensive answer, much appreciated. Accidently I'd found [kind of documentation/guide - Using Counters in Mathematica](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/nbarch/2018/10/2018-10-10r84uo/CounterTutorial.nb) which was written by Paul J. Hinton in 1998 (probably for version 3) that could perhaps make your answer pluperfect.

Comment: @BenIzd Thanks & nice find! The Front End menus have changed a little since that was written, but maybe/probably the rest is accurate.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use `CounterBox` for this purpose:

```
makeFig[expr_] := (
    CellPrint[Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[expr]], "Figure"]];
    CellPrint[Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"Fig. ", CounterBox["Figure"]}]], "FigureCaption"]]
)
```

Comment: Thank you. There is one problem with this idea. I need to be able to give cross-references to these graphics in the text. Therefore, I need the graphics cell to be tagged. I tried the following modification of your code: `makeFig[expr_, 
  tag_String] := (CellPrint[
   Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[expr]], "Figure", CellTags -> "Fig" <> tag, , 
    TextAlignment -> Center]];
  CellPrint[
   Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"Fig. ", CounterBox["Figure"]}]], 
    "FigureCaption", TextAlignment -> Center]])`.

Comment: (continuation) This nicely makes the enumeration of the figures. However, as soon as I try to go to a text cell and enter a reference, I see that Menu/Insert/AutomaticNumbering menu element is ausblended for whatever reason. Do you have a remedy for that?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch it works for me. What does ausblended mean?

Comment: Yes, after I waited for some time it started working for me too. Looks good. I will test it more tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

A very basic solution was discussed in the comments but as mentioned, each time you call, the index increments without considering the cell position.

This solution will assign a `CellTag` to each `FigureCaption` cell it generates and uses `Cells[]` with `EvaluationCell[]` to count the number of generated cells before it. In this method it doesn't matter how many times you execute the cell, it'll output the cell unless you'd inserted another figure previously.

> I'm sure the OP can understand the final code, I'll explain this, so everybody can understand.

Let's assume you, we'll assign tag `"FG"` to `FigureCaption` cells we generate.

`Cells[]` return all the cells of the current notebook, with the code below we can take all the previous cells of the current evaluated cell:

```
TakeWhile[Cells[], # =!= EvaluationCell[] &]
```

Now we need to count the `"FG"`s since some cells can have one Tag and unfortunately, (it seems) Mathematica **does not** warp it in tags `List` if it's a single tag, here is how we count them:

```
Count[TakeWhile[Cells[], # =!= EvaluationCell[] &], 
 x_ /; Block[{temp = CurrentValue[x, CellTags]}, 
   temp === "FG" || MemberQ[temp, "FG"]]]
```

Here is the final code:

```
ClearAll[makeFig3];

makeFig3[expr_, tag_String] := 
 Module[{}, 
  CellPrint[
   ExpressionCell[expr, "Figure", TextAlignment -> Center, 
    CellTags -> "Fig" <> tag]];
  CellPrint[
   TextCell[
    "Fig. " <> 
     ToString[1+
      Count[TakeWhile[Cells[], # =!= EvaluationCell[] &], 
       x_ /; Block[{temp = CurrentValue[x, CellTags]}, 
         temp === "FG" || MemberQ[temp, "FG"]]]], "FigureCaption", 
    CellTags -> "FG", FontSize -> 12, TextAlignment -> Center]];]
```

Example:

[image]